# Error mounting drive at service startup (ExecStartPre)

Tags: mount, bash, systemd, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, permissions

As a precondition for starting my Syncthing service, I wish to mount an external USB drive (label `MyBook`). The action must be synchronous, so putting it anywhere else besides the service's `ExecStartPre` will not be sufficient. The mount must be a hard dependency of successful service startup. Rule: if the mount fails for any reason, the service doesn't start.

I should note that I had this working on another RPi3B+, running the same OS version. The problem here, though, comes when the script called by the service attempts to mount the drive. Here's that script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if /dev/sda1 is already mounted
if ! grep -qs '/dev/sda1' /proc/mounts; then
    # Mount /dev/sda1 to /media/pi/MyBook
    echo "Mounting /dev/sda1 to /media/pi/MyBook"
    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/pi/MyBook
fi
```

I've added the user running the service (`admin`) to the `sudoers` file using `visudo` and rebooted for good measure:

```
admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
```

Here's my error at service startup (`journalctl` doesn't reveal anything further than this):

```
pi@RPI:~ $ sudo systemctl status syncthing@admin.service
● syncthing@admin.service - Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for admin
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/syncthing@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/syncthing@admin.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-02-21 17:23:14 AKST; 33s ago
       Docs: man:syncthing(1)
    Process: 959 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/mount-sync-drive.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 53ms

Feb 21 17:23:14 RPI systemd[1]: syncthing@admin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Feb 21 17:23:14 RPI systemd[1]: Stopped Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for admin.
Feb 21 17:23:14 RPI systemd[1]: syncthing@admin.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 21 17:23:14 RPI systemd[1]: syncthing@admin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 21 17:23:14 RPI systemd[1]: Failed to start Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for admin.
```

Note that when I mount the drive manually and comment out the line of code that performs the mount, the service starts successfully. I can also run the script manually (when logged in as `admin`) without any problem.

I considered the possibility of a permissions error during mounting, but that theory went by the wayside when I compared permissions against the Pi on which this was working. All is the same:

```
pi@RPI:~ $ sudo ls -lahR /media/pi/MyBook/
/media/pi/MyBook/:
total 16K
drwxrwxrwx  4 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 3 root  root  4.0K Feb 20 16:17 ..
drwx------  3 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 .config

/media/pi/MyBook/.config:
total 12K
drwx------ 3 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 ..
drwx------ 3 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 syncthing

/media/pi/MyBook/.config/syncthing:
total 52K
drwx------ 3 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 .
drwx------ 3 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  794 Feb 21 15:00 cert.pem
-rw------- 1 admin admin 6.5K Feb 21 15:00 config.xml
-rw------- 1 admin admin 4.8K Feb 21 15:00 config.xml.v0
-rw------- 1 admin admin 3.8K Feb 21 15:00 config.xml.v32
-rw------- 1 admin admin  231 Feb 21 15:00 csrftokens.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  769 Feb 21 15:00 https-cert.pem
-rw------- 1 admin admin  288 Feb 21 15:00 https-key.pem
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 17:21 index-v0.14.0.db
-rw------- 1 admin admin  288 Feb 21 15:00 key.pem

/media/pi/MyBook/.config/syncthing/index-v0.14.0.db:
total 300K
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 17:21 .
drwx------ 3 admin admin 4.0K Feb 21 15:00 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  623 Feb 21 15:00 001319.ldb
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  293 Feb 21 16:48 001332.ldb
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  260 Feb 21 16:49 001333.ldb
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  279 Feb 21 16:59 001336.ldb
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  356 Feb 21 17:21 001339.ldb
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  546 Feb 21 17:22 001340.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin   16 Feb 21 17:21 CURRENT
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin   16 Feb 21 17:21 CURRENT.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin    0 Feb 21 15:00 LOCK
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 253K Feb 21 17:22 LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 1.1K Feb 21 17:21 MANIFEST-001341
```

Besides, all of that works fine when the drive is pre-mounted and the script's `if` condition is never satisfied.

And finally, here's my `ExecStartPre`:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/mount-sync-drive.sh
```

All of the troubleshooting steps shown here are the results of a full day's research on the problem. I've now reached a dead end, I'm afraid.

How can I find out why this script won't mount my drive at service startup?

**--EDIT--**

Here's some error logging, captured via advice in the answer by @goldilocks:

```
Wed 22 Feb 15:57:43 AKST 2023
Mounting /dev/sda1 to /media/pi/MyBook
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

Wed 22 Feb 15:57:44 AKST 2023
Mounting /dev/sda1 to /media/pi/MyBook
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

Wed 22 Feb 15:57:45 AKST 2023
Mounting /dev/sda1 to /media/pi/MyBook
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

Wed 22 Feb 15:57:46 AKST 2023
Mounting /dev/sda1 to /media/pi/MyBook
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

That error message seems a bit mysterious to me. `sudo` appears to be OK on my system:

```
pi@RPI:/usr/local/bin $ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 178432 Jan 14 04:29 /usr/bin/sudo
```

And the mount seems OK (even when I run the script manually as `admin`):

```
pi@RPI:~ $ mount -v | grep sda1
pi@RPI:~ $ sudo -u admin /usr/local/bin/mount-sync-drive.sh
mount: /dev/sda1 mounted on /media/pi/MyBook.
pi@RPI:~ $ mount -v | grep sda1
/dev/sda1 on /media/pi/MyBook type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

These outputs are exactly the same as the outputs on the Pi (again: same model, same OS, installed new within the hour on the same day using the same configuration, excepting the hostname) where the scripted mount is working. Also, `sudo visudo` shows both files to be the same on both systems.

The error message appears to be an important clue, but I'm unable to decipher its exact meaning. Search results aren't turning up anything meaningful (or specific to this situation).

My first guess was that the service somehow isn't running the script as `admin`, but that can't be the case since the status under service failure shows that it did indeed run under `admin`:

```
Feb 22 15:57:47 RPI systemd[1]: Failed to start Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization for admin. <-- username substitution for %I here
```

How to understand what the error means? Further, how to identify and fix the actual problem that it's pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out why this script won't mount my drive at service startup?

You have an `echo` in there but don't mention whether this output is captured when run as a service at boot.  If it isn't, `mount` is probably emitting an error that you never see.

`journalctl -u [service_name]` may or may not help you out there. The best way to do this, however, is to either add this at the beginning of the script:

```
exec &> /some/log/path
```

Where `/some/log/path` must be writable by the `admin` user, **or** (not and) add to the service file in the `[Service]` section:

```
StandardOutput=file:/some/log/path
StandardError=inherit  # Paranoid since this is the default.
```

You'll need to `systemctl daemon-reload` if you want to test that without rebooting.  Again, the path should be writable for `admin`.

You can also make `mount` more verbose by using `-v`.  Both of the above methods will overwrite anything from any previous run unless you rotate the log first.<sup>1</sup>  If you want to keep and append to the log instead, use `exec &>>` (vs. `&>`) or `StandardOutput=append:/path`.  If you do this, a nice command to add at the top of the script (after `exec &>>`, if used), is `date`.

The systemd output options are explained in greater detail in `man systemd.exec`.

---

1. More specifically what systemd `file:` will do is overwrite from the beginning of the file without clobbering (truncating) it first, which can get confusing.  To clobber properly, use `truncate:` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work on this today and get back to you asap.

Comment: I preferred the `exec &>>` approach, as it allows for inserting timestamps in the log file. Nice trick. The plot thickens—see my edit—but the solution still eludes me. What does the error indicate to you? I've managed to eliminate the possibilities described in the message itself, so what else could it be? The script works fine when run manually under the context of `admin`, but not when run by the service. And it's only on this system, which is 90% identical to the one where it's working. Maddening!

Comment: A timestamp in the script will be the same regardless of which method you use.  WRT `nosuid`, you should ask that in a new question, probably at [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  You could try adding `mount | grep nosuid` (no need for `sudo`) to the script to see which filesystems have this set at the time; try it normally and you will see a lot of virtual/in mem fs mounts with that set, including on `/dev`.

Comment: ...The fact that the script works when run admin after boot possibly implies the root fs is mounted that way at the time (it gets re-mounted at least once); if so you could try `local-fs.target` as a dependency.

Comment: +1, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Guess I ought not to go trying to move the goalposts, eh...?  *"you should ask that in a new question"* Yes, I've done exactly [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/736645).

Comment: Also, I can see now that it's a problem running `sudo`, not `mount` per se. Your `mount` sans `sudo` tip cleared that up for me. A couple of lingering questions, though, if I may: 1) When you say *"try it normally"*, I presume what you mean by *"normally"* is at the command prompt, as opposed to at runtime via service startup, yes? 2) I'm not at all sure what you mean by *"try local-fs.target as a dependency"*. Could you clarify?

Comment: WRT "normally" yeah, the point about `mount | grep nosuid` is easiest to get by just doing it.  WRT `local-fs.target`, this is a standard systemd target, but it sounds like that is not the problem.  I'm not a big sudo user, interesting it is kind of shut out of sysd.  I think you should just make the mount a separate `Type=oneshot` service run as root, then make it a `Requires` and `After` Sycnthing dependency (have a look at `man systemd.unit` for the fine tuning that can be done that way).

Comment: Hm, interesting. I'll have to have a look at that. In the meantime, though, I've implemented a clunky workaround so I can at least get this thing into production. I put an infinite loop into the script, with a one-second sleep, that breaks when the mount is found. I then added the mount to `/etc/fstab` and rebooted. The service started and ran, so I kicked off a two-day file sync job. So further troubleshooting/configuration is on hold for the duration. But I'll try this and get back to you asap. Thanks so much for your assistance.

Comment: That's not all that clunky; personally I'd prefer to use fstab automounting if that is ok in context.  WRT the check/wait it might of course be nicer if you could just wait for a callback or something but in the end that is much the same as a passive (sleep based) loop anyway.  Even if it never gets mounted for whatever reason that is harmless, and it has the advantage of being drop dead simple.

Comment: I ended up using the `[mount]` / `[unit]` construct, as illustrated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736853). It works great. Perhaps you were already referring to that; I'm not sure.

Comment: _"That's not all that clunky"_ Aw, shucks... I don't know what to say 

Comment: That's more or less what I meant, yes.